# Tomcat 7 and shared.loader problem

Tags: tomcat, properties, classpath

I am using a custom directory for properties files located at

```
${catalina.home}/conf/properties
```

and in order to add it to the classpath i edited ctalina.properties and added

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/conf/properties
```

But contents of this directory are not accessible when I try to read them from a listener via:

```
MyListener.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample.props")
```

I most probably have misunderstood something here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("/sample.props");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works on various installations of Tomcat (so I can do my job) but unfortunately it fails on Tomcat 7 / Windows 7 x64.

Comment: It works for me with Tomcat 7.0.20 on Windows 7 x64 (after Tomcat restart and application redeploy).

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with : Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("sample.props");